# React Native - Moving up screen in TextInput with KeyboardAvoidingView

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a view with some TextInputs, and some of them are in the bottom part of the screen. The thing is I want the screen to move up when I click on them to that way I can see what I'm writing. I searched a lot but nothing works for me, I have my view nested in a KeyboardAvoidingView but nothing happens when I click on the TextInput. Here's my code:

```
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
            keyboardVerticalOffset={64}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
        >
            <View style={styles.screen}>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
                    <TextInput
                        value={title}
                        onChangeText={text => setTitle(text)}
                        style={styles.singleLineTextInput}
                        placeholder="Title"
                    />

                    <TextInput
                        value={keywords}
                        onChangeText={text => setKeywords(text)}
                        style={styles.singleLineTextInput}
                        placeholder="Keywords"
                    />

                    <TextInput
                        value={description}
                        onChangeText={text => setDescription(text)}
                        style={{ ...styles.singleLineTextInput, ...styles.descriptionTextInput }}
                        placeholder="Description"
                        multiline={true}
                        autoFocus={true}
                    />
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView >
```

And my styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 16,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    singleLineTextInput: {
        width: DEVICE_WIDTH * 0.8,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
        fontSize: 16,
        paddingHorizontal: 16
    },
    descriptionTextInput: {
        maxHeight: DEVICE_HEIGHT / 4
    }
});
```

I'm using React-Navigation and I tried changing *keyboardVertialOffset* and *behavior* to multiples values but nothing happens. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Import Content from native-base as

```
import { Content } from 'native-base';
```

And import platform from react-native

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
```

And use content and platform in your code like this:

```
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
           behavior={Platform.Os == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"} 
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
        ><Content>
            <View style={styles.screen}>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
                    <TextInput
                        value={title}
                        onChangeText={text => setTitle(text)}
                        style={styles.singleLineTextInput}
                        placeholder="Title"
                    />

                    <TextInput
                        value={keywords}
                        onChangeText={text => setKeywords(text)}
                        style={styles.singleLineTextInput}
                        placeholder="Keywords"
                    />

                    <TextInput
                        value={description}
                        onChangeText={text => setDescription(text)}
                        style={{ ...styles.singleLineTextInput, ...styles.descriptionTextInput }}
                        placeholder="Description"
                        multiline={true}
                        autoFocus={true}
                    />
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

            </View>
           </Content>

        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Doesn't work for me.. Nothing changes when I add it :(

Comment: can  you remove TouchableWithoutFeedback  and try it once